# how to build domain based Multi-tenant SaaS solution built using OWIN claims based authentication

Tags: owin, wif, claims-based-identity, acs, katana

I'm attempting to create a SaaS solution and i want each tenant of my application to have its own Access Control Service (ACS) server or identity server configuration, I plan on determining the current tenant by the subdomain currently being visited

eg tenant1.Myapp.com, tenant2.Myapp.com

I want to be able to have different tenant config for each tenant and i don't want each tenant to be aware of other tenants currently registered.

I will have custom branding for each tenant

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() { LoginPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/Authentication/SignIn") });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                MetadataAddress = "https://XXXXX.accesscontrol.windows.net/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml",
                Wtrealm = "urn:operations.web"
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The above code works for a single tenant application but there is no way of knowing in advance which of the ACS identity providers to use for authentication.

Some of the tenants want to be able to login users using Google, Microsoft Account, Facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using ACS to enable multiple IPs in your application. That's a great first step though the ACS functionality is under process to be folded into the AAD.

In your case you need to download the json feed of all your IPs from the ACS and then filter it based on the information in the request headers that contains the subdomain name.

Mu blog post here takes you all the way to this point and then you need to go the rest of the way yourself.

http://magnusmartensson.com/mvc-application-using-owin-to-achieve-federated-authentication

A typical ACS json feed address looks something like this:

https://{mytenant}.accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/metadata/IdentityProviders.js?protocol=wsfederation&realm=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a7664%2f&reply_to=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a7664%2f&context=&request_id=&version=1.0&callback=

When you get on that feed you will receive an array of your configured IPs in the ACS:

```
[
{"Name":"Windows Live™ ID","LoginUrl":"https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2faccesscontrol.windows.net%2f&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fSOMENAME.accesscontrol.windows.net%2fv2%2fwsfederation&wp=MBI_FED_SSL&wctx=cHI9d3NmZWRlcmF0aW9uJnJtPWh0dHAlM2ElMmYlMmZsb2NhbGhvc3QlM2E3NjY0JTJmJnJ5PWh0dHAlM2ElMmYlMmZsb2NhbGhvc3QlM2E3NjY0JTJm0","LogoutUrl":"https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignout1.0","ImageUrl":"","EmailAddressSuffixes":[]},
{"Name":"Google","LoginUrl":"https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.ns=http%3a%2f%2fspecs.openid.net%2fauth%2f2.0&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.claimed_id=http%3a%2f%2fspecs.openid.net%2fauth%2f2.0%2fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3a%2f%2fspecs.openid.net%2fauth%2f2.0%2fidentifier_select&openid.realm=https%3a%2f%2fSOMENAME.accesscontrol.windows.net%3a443%2fv2%2fopenid&openid.return_to=https%3a%2f%2fSOMENAME.accesscontrol.windows.net%3a443%2fv2%2fopenid%3fcontext%3dcHI9d3NmZWRlcmF0aW9uJnJtPWh0dHAlM2ElMmYlMmZsb2NhbGhvc3QlM2E3NjY0JTJmJnJ5PWh0dHAlM2ElMmYlMmZsb2NhbGhvc3QlM2E3NjY0JTJmJnByb3ZpZGVyPUdvb2dsZQ2&openid.ns.ax=http%3a%2f%2fopenid.net%2fsrv%2fax%2f1.0&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.ax.required=email%2cfullname%2cfirstname%2clastname&openid.ax.type.email=http%3a%2f%2faxschema.org%2fcontact%2femail&openid.ax.type.fullname=http%3a%2f%2faxschema.org%2fnamePerson&openid.ax.type.firstname=http%3a%2f%2faxschema.org%2fnamePerson%2ffirst&openid.ax.type.lastname=http%3a%2f%2faxschema.org%2fnamePerson%2flast","LogoutUrl":"https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout","ImageUrl":"","EmailAddressSuffixes":[]},
{"Name":"SOMENAME","LoginUrl":"https://login.windows.net/3c54a3bf-d2b0-4dae-bdd6-61d05145c8be/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fviewmybox.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fviewmybox.accesscontrol.windows.net%2fv2%2fwsfederation&wctx=cHI9d3NmZWRlcmF0aW9uJnJtPWh0dHAlM2ElMmYlMmZsb2NhbGhvc3QlM2E3NjY0JTJmJnJ5PWh0dHAlM2ElMmYlMmZsb2NhbGhvc3QlM2E3NjY0JTJm0","LogoutUrl":"https://login.windows.net/3c54a3bf-d2b0-4dae-bdd6-61d05145c8be/wsfed?wa=wsignout1.0","ImageUrl":"","EmailAddressSuffixes":[]},
{"Name":"Facebook","LoginUrl":"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=284082335104349&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fviewmybox.accesscontrol.windows.net%2fv2%2ffacebook%3fcx%3dcHI9d3NmZWRlcmF0aW9uJnJtPWh0dHAlM2ElMmYlMmZsb2NhbGhvc3QlM2E3NjY0JTJmJnJ5PWh0dHAlM2ElMmYlMmZsb2NhbGhvc3QlM2E3NjY0JTJmJmlwPUZhY2Vib29rLTI4NDA4MjMzNTEwNDM0OQ2&scope=email","LogoutUrl":"https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token={0}&next={1}","ImageUrl":"","EmailAddressSuffixes":[]},
{"Name":"Martensson Consulting","LoginUrl":"https://login.windows.net/8e717ff8-8b9b-4185-b61c-aea1fd724035/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fviewmybox.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&wreply=https%3a%2f%2fviewmybox.accesscontrol.windows.net%2fv2%2fwsfederation&wctx=cHI9d3NmZWRlcmF0aW9uJnJtPWh0dHAlM2ElMmYlMmZsb2NhbGhvc3QlM2E3NjY0JTJmJnJ5PWh0dHAlM2ElMmYlMmZsb2NhbGhvc3QlM2E3NjY0JTJm0","LogoutUrl":"https://login.windows.net/8e717ff8-8b9b-4185-b61c-aea1fd724035/wsfed?wa=wsignout1.0","ImageUrl":"","EmailAddressSuffixes":[]}
```

]

Naturally you only want to use one of a couple of these IPs for each of your subdomains/tenants/customers. What you need to do is server side filter this feed and provide your login page with only the ones your customer accepts. If it's only one you might even want to redirect from your application straight to that one single option for customer sign in.

This requires you download the login sample page from the ACS and build your own custom version.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How about after the user has been authenticated how do you make th ACS return the user back to the correct tenant1.MyApp.com?

Comment: There is a reply_to adress in addition to the realm attributes in the url you use to fetch the IPs from ACS above. Also you can use the context parameter to send any context data through the authentication process (encrypted) and back to you when the user returns with her token from the IP through the ACS.